# Apply event on children element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to write my custom jquery tooltip code for selected dropdown list.below is my html code structure.I want to display tooltip on hover of ? (question mark) in span tag. I have write jquery code but it does not work.My question is that how apply event of children element (like span children of div).I have already tried below jquery code but it does not work.

Dropdown fill up on page load using ajax.

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // first code not working

    $('#sub_cat_tooltip').hover(function(){
        alert("Title :"+$("#subcat option:selected").attr( "title"));
    });

    // second code not working

    $('#subcatdrp p #sub_cat_tooltip').hover(function(){
        alert("Title :"+$("#subcat option:selected").attr( "title"));
    });

    // third code not working

    $('#subcatdrp > p > #sub_cat_tooltip').hover(function(){
        alert("Title :"+$("#subcat option:selected").attr( "title"));
    }); 

    // fourth 
    // try all above try using onmouseover event

    $('#sub_cat_tooltip').onmouseover(function(){
        alert("Title :"+$("#subcat option:selected").attr( "title"));
    });
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="subcatdrp">
    <p>
        <label for="subcategory">Sub Category:</label>
        <select id="subcat" name="subcat">
        </select>
    </p>
    <span id="sub_cat_tooltip" class="tooltip_img">?</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: "_it does not work_" - what _does_ it do?

Comment: Works for me WHEN there are some options in the dropdown. In the HTML you posted, there are none. Also, note your hover callback will fire on both mouseenter and mouseleave, as you provide only one callback, not two. You probably want `$('#sub_cat_tooltip').on('mouseenter', function()...` instead.

Comment: I want to call jquery hover function on it.but it is not call

Comment: @Utkanos thank for your suggestion.May be you are right but my problem is my dropdown filled up at run time using ajax so i want to know that because of this dynamic code the hover event is not worked.

Comment: In that case you need to put your code inside a success callback to the AJAX request - i.e. you must ensure your code executes after AJAX success, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/wCBbM/), although it fires twice, since `.hover` with a single argument calls it upon mouseenter and mouseleave. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/wCBbM/1/) a fixed version.

#### 2 and 3

`$('#subcatdrp p #sub_cat_tooltip')` and `$('#subcatdrp > p > #sub_cat_tooltip')` do not work because they looks for this HTML:

```
<... id="subcatdrp">
    <p>
         <... id="sub_cat_tooltip" /> 
    </p>
</...>
```

Your tooltip is not inside the p.

#### 4

`onmouseover` does not work because it does not exist in jQuery. You're looking for `.mouseenter`.

Comment: I have try your code but it gives me error.Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @Harry: Does the page I linked to work? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes example working correctly.I have used Chrome latest version on linux

Comment: If the example works, then you're doing something wrong. I can't possibly know where it is. Have you tried... fixing the syntax error?

Comment: I have used jquery 1.2.3 then after i have replaced it with jquery 1.7.2 and got the error specified

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13548/discussion-between-eric-and-harry)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

**HTML Code**

```
<div>
    <p>
        <label for="subcategory1">Sub Category:</label>
        <select name="subcategory1" title="This is title 1!">
        </select>
    </p>
    <span class="tooltip_img">?</span> 
</div>

<div>
    <p>
        <label for="subcategory2">Sub Category:</label>
        <select name="subcategory2" title="This is title 2!">
        </select>
    </p>
    <span class="tooltip_img">?</span> 
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip_img').mouseover(function() {
        var $alert = $(this).parent().find('select').attr('title');
        alert($alert);
    });
});
```

Comment: **-1** Duplicate IDs - not even once